# Python doesn't write all entries from list

Tags: python, file, list, join

I'm exploring python and tried to sort all files from a directory by last modified and then write the list into a txt file.

```
    import time
    import os
    i=1
    a="path"
    def getfiles(dirpat):
        b = [s for s in os.listdir(dirpat)
             if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirpat, s))]
        b.sort(key=lambda s: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dirpat, s)))
        return b
    lyst=[]
    testfile='c://test.txt'
    lyst=getfiles(a)
    for x in range (0,len(lyst)):
        print lyst[x]    
        fileHandle = open (testfile, 'w' )    
        fileHandle.write ("\n".join(str(lyst[x])))
        fileHandle.close()
```

It printed perfectly and sorted by date also

```
    example1.pdf
    example3.docx
    example4.docx
    exmaple2.docx
    example 5.doc
```

But when I opened the file, it just had the last entry and displayed it like this

```
    e
    x
    a
    ... and so on
```

Just can't figure out where the problem lies. If I remove "\n".join it just prints me the last entry.

Thanks in advance,
Nils

Comment: Please do not **ever** have lines like `list = []` and `file = 'c://test.txt'` (the `list` one in particular). These are builtins which you shouldn't shadow. What happens after that if you want to call `list(some_iterable)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct the `join()`, e.g:

```
'\n'.join(str(path) for path in list)
```

And please rename the "list" variable, because `list` is a built-in data type in Python.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os, os.path

a="path"

def getfiles(dirpat):
    b = [s for s in os.listdir(dirpat)
         if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirpat, s))]
    b.sort(key=lambda s: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dirpat, s)))
    return b

outfile='c://test.txt'

with open(outfile, 'w') as fileHandle:
    lines = getfiles(a)
    for line in lines:
        print line
        fileHandle.write(line)
```

Avoid using meaningless one character variable names. I also did not touch your getfiles() function. I did, however, rename `file` and `list` as those are both the names of built in functions, which you're hiding when you use those names.

You also only need to open the file once, not once per line. You were truncating the file on every write. Using `with` makes sure the file handle gets closed even if you have an error.

Edit: If you don't need to print out each line before writing it, you can just have one line inside the `with` block: `fileHandle.writelines(getfiles(a))`.

Comment: Best answer yet, in that it removed the `range(len())` confusion, improved naming, and fixed both errors.

Comment: It wrote the entries into the file without nextline. So they we're stacked together. But all-in-all the remake was quite better than mine

Answer (score 2):

Do this when writing the file:

```
fileHandle = open (file, 'w' )  
for listItem in list:
    print listItem    
    fileHandle.write (str(listItem) + "\n")
fileHandle.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are opening and overwriting the file contents in each iteration of the loop.

Pass 'a' to the `open(path)` call to append to the file, or simply open it once outside the loop and close it outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Because you convert each entry in the list to `str` the join operates on each
`str` because they also count as iterables and therefore a `\n` is put between
each character, not every item in the list. Changing the line to `fileHandle.write ('\n'.join(str(path) for path in list)))` will fix this just like BasicWolf wrote.